# How can I render an URL path from a custom route?

Tags: routes

In my module.routing.yml (and using D8), I have a *module_new* route associated with the /module/name path.

I want to render this path in my module. How can I show http://example.org/module/name on a page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Twig**

You can use the route name in the twig function `url()`:

```
<a href="{{ url('module_new') }}">{{ 'View my module content'|t }}</a>
```

**Controller**

Or you can do the same in a controller:

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

  $url = Url::fromRoute('module_new', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]);

  // get the path as string (not recommended)
  $path = $url->toString;

  // better put the complete url object in a render array and let the template render it
  $build['link'] = [
   '#title' => $this->t('My module content'),
   '#type' => 'link',
   '#url' => $url,
  ];

  return $build;
```

Comment: How can I use this in my controller handler ?

Comment: I use Url::fromRoute('module_new')  but it's not string and not work .

Comment: :D , I change it to string with ->toString() but not show http :// mysite in string . How can I do this ?

Comment: Not work and not show http:// example .org in my link . I don't want to use $link . I want create http:// example .org/module/name to use in other variables .

Comment: it's better to use the url as object in a render element to build the link, but you can get the path as string, see the edit

Comment: Thanks @4k4 but I want just show text of url not link .

Comment: you can set the option `absolute`, then you get the full path, see edit